# Jquery, qtip and FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

I am trying to integrate qtip2 with my FullCalendar on this test site: http://www.pilatesintuition.co.uk/test/pilates-classes.html

Unfortunately I just cannot get qtip to trigger - can anyone tell me what I have done wrong with my coding?  I am new to jquery etc. so don't understand yet how it all works.

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/pilatesintuition%40gmail.com/public/basic'
    })
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 400
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myEvents = [];
    var date = new Date();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var length = 12;

    for (var month = 1; month < length; month++) {
        var month = (month <= 9) ? '0' + month : month;
        var startdate = y + '-' + month + '-10';
        var enddate = y + '-0' + month + '-15';
        myEvents.push({
            title: 'event',
            start: startdate,
            //end: enddate,
            description: 'event Of ' + startdate,
            allDay: true
        });
    }

    $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
        events: myEvents,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description
        });
        }
    });

    });
});</script>
```

Please can anyone tell me what I have done wrong here?  I have uploaded the jquery.qtip.min.js file and linked it to my page.  I also found the above code on this site: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/XyNnH/

Thanks in advance.